# Multi-locale is not working with routes

Tags: localization, routes

I have a localization problem where the routes are not showing up.
I have a tried a routes file with the following code.

```
return array(
    'menu' => '_menu'
)
```

And its working on the main language but when i put 
`website.com/ar/menu` its giving me `404` as if the route doesnt exist.

I have a subfolder with the proper `index.php` and `.htaccess`

How can i fix this issue in the right way?

Comment: Where is your “_menu” template located? (e.g. craft/templates/_menu.html)